# How to import names+phone numbers into my Android smartphone (a Galaxy S3)?

Tags: import

I have an Android Galaxy S3 phone and I have a two column lists of names + phone numbers on my hard disk, and a Google account, and am a capable programmer and software developer. How can I import the phone numbers into the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No programming is required in this case. You need to make little changes to you text file so that it looks like below:

================

Name,Phone

Rakesh Patel,9825798257

Ramesh Patel,8758965854

==============

1. First row should be column header: Name, Phone
2. Name and number should have a comma as a separator.
3. change file extension to *.csv

Then Go to [Google contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts) ==> click  More and select Import and upload the CSV file.

This will import all your contacts to Google account. 
Then add same google account to your Device (if not added already).
If Sync option is already enabled, your contacts, calendar etc. will start syncing with Google account data when your device is connected to internet. (If sync is disabled, you need to enable it first)

Comment: Helpful tips from Google themselves: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12119?hl=en